# When everything hangs except the mouse pointer

Tags: linux, debian, freeze

It has happened to me a few times that Debian hangs completely except that I can still move the mouse pointer. However, no application responds when clicking around and I cannot reboot the computer or switch TTY with the keyboard. My question is what generally causes this kind of error. Is there a log I can look in to find out? Today it happened when I used Google image search in Firefox.

I run Debian 12.4 with the Blackbox window manager. All applications are installed from the standard (default) repositories.

**Edit**: Here is the output of `free`:

```
$ free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         7847600     1671108     4962320       12524     1489896     6176492
Swap:         999420           0      999420
```

Comment: OK so, as it seems (unless in multi-seat configuration) the display server (X ?) is still alive but the window manager has gone for some coffee break or died prematurely. Some log should tell you more.

Comment: Do you have swap space defined? `free` will tell you. It looks like you're in an Out-Of-Memory condition. Read `man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab`.

Comment: @waltinator I have the default amount of swap space (chosen by the Debian installer). I added the output from `free` to the question.

Comment: It could be that your GPU driver has partially crashed. Try to press "Ctrl + Alt + Backspace" or SSH in remotely and run `sudo killall -9 Xorg`.